# Validate CSS syntax with C#

Tags: c#, .net, css, validation, syntax

I'm searching for a function (perhaps there is one in the .Net-Framework) which I can use to validate CSS-syntax for different version (CSS 3.0, 2.0). It can also be a CSS parser with build-in validation. Any suggestions for a library or tool that i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at ExCSS, it can parse CSS 2.1 and CSS 3,

https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS

Comment: Actually I was little overwhelmed with this one don't know how to use and the sample provided is not that useful..

Answer (score 1):

for validation, try **regex**, 
try this pattern `/([A-Za-z0-9 ]+:[A-Za-z0-9 ]+;$)+/i`